# Delete Directory on Git Repository that cannot be Pulled to PC

Tags: git, github

While working on a mac my IDE generated a directory containing the `:` (colon) character, which got pushed to the git repository. When I switched to work on my PC later I discovered that I was unable to pull the directory, receiving a `fatal: cannot create directory at... invalid argument` error.

**How can I delete or rename an unpullable directory?**

I am using GitHub.com, so solutions using the website interface are also acceptable.

Comment: "While working on a mac" - why don't you delete it from mac?

Comment: The mac is at work and I need to pull the changes onto my home computer tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember that `git pull` is actually a two step process.First it uses `fetch` to retrieve the remote files. Then it will try to do a `fast-forward` `merge` to apply the changes on top of your working directly.

So use `fetch` on the remote. This will make sure you have the remote change set in your git repo. I'd say run the following from the git repo:

```
ls | xargs -I'{}' git checkout -- '{}'
```

but you said you're on a Windows box so you may just have to loop through and do that manually. Also this assumes that no new files were created in the root of your repo.

Now, if you actually want to revert the creation of the directory, do the following (this assumes the remote as `origin` and the branch as `master`).

```sh
git update-ref refs/heads/master $(git rev-parse origin/master)
git add --all .
# amend the commit to remove the folder from history
# only do this if you can rebase the remote w/o repercussion
git commit --amend
# otherwise just add a new commit on top of the old
git commit
```

Now look at the logs to see if everything looks fine, and if it does then push up to the remote (if you used `--amend` then you'll have to force push).